# When is the analysis chain created for Edge N Gram in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I was trying to figure out which one is better for incremental search - edge n gramm or completion suggester. So far what I have read on Internet suggested that for completion suggester processing of data is done at the time of index creation whereas for edge n gram its done at query time, hence its slower than completion suggester. However just now in the Elasticsearch - The definitve guide, book I read that for edge n gram also its done at indexing time. Now I am really confused, can anyone please clear however edge n gram internally works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both act at index time, building dedicated data structures:

- N gram tokenizer generates tokens: "hello world" becomes "h", "he", "hel"... "worl", "world". A usual "text" (aka "string") mapping type is used.
- completion suggester generates a graph: see https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me . At this point, there is a special mapping type "completion".

At search time, suggester are less expensive:

- N gram tokenizer:

  - typed text must be analyzed, resulting terms searched: searched "Hello Wor" should be analyzed into "hello"+"wor" and these 2 terms searched.
  - Yet, the N gram tokenizer should be removed from analysis (use a different analyzer between search and indexing): searching "Henry" would be analyzed "h", "he", "hen", "henr"... and would return "hello" because they share the same prefix "he".
- completion suggester is simpler and quicker. If you're trying to autocomplete search as user types on keyboard, performance is important.

In both cases, you can use custom analysis chains (french, german, soundex...):

- N grams:

  - Write time: custom analysis + edge ngram + type "text"
  - Read time: custom analysis + truncate + search API
- Completion

  - Write time: custom analysis + type "completion"
  - Read time: custom analysis + suggest API

Comment: hi, could you please elaborate "N gram tokenizer: typed text must be analyzed, resulting terms searched. Yet, the N gram tokenizer should be removed (use a different analyzer between search and indexing)".

Comment: If the text is analyzed than the existing graph would be that useful right? for example if I use phonetic analyzer then ifone would also find iphone, but I woudn't have that in my already generated tokens.